# JavaFX - How to make text wrap inside a TableColumn in TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview, scenebuilder, tablecolumn

I'm having trouble working out how to get my text to wrap inside a TableView. Here is how i'm currently initializing my TableColumn.

```
col_time.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("time"));
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

I've worked out how to make the text wrap inside my column using

```
col_task.setCellFactory(tc -> {
            TableCell<ModelTable, String> cell = new TableCell<>();
            Text text = new Text();
            cell.setGraphic(text);
            cell.setPrefHeight(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
            text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(col_task.widthProperty());
            text.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());
            return cell ;
        });
```

But i wanted to be able to edit my text inside table view whilst it remained wrapped. I was originally using

```
col_task.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

Any ideas how to keep my text wrapped whilst the cell remains as TextField?

Comment: implement a custom cell that uses a TextArea (TextField doens't wrap - afair, didn't check the doc)

Comment: and unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: What naming conventions did i get wrong? I'm new to Java and thereis a lot to remember.

Comment: true :) the convention is to use camelCase instead of underscores